# Scroll to bottom on new Message

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, chat

I have an Angular application, where I'm facing a problem with the automatic scroll to the bottom in my chat container, whenever a new message arrives.

**My Template**

```
<div #msgContainer class="chat-box-body" appInfiniteScroll (scrollTop)="loadOlderMessages()">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let msg of conversation.messages.edges">
  <ng-container *ngIf="msg.node?.from?.id !== currentUser.id; else myMsg">
    <div class="sender-msg-block">
      <div class="wrapper-left">
        <img class="sender-dp"
             [src]="conversation.conversation_participants[0].conversable?.profile_picture?.url ||  'assets/images/no-user.svg'">
        <p class="sender-msg">{{msg.node.body}}</p>
        <span class="sender-time">{{msg.node.created_at}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #myMsg>
    <div #newMesssage class="receiver-msg-block">
      <div class="wrapper-right">
        <span class="receiver-time">{{msg.node.created_at}}</span>
        <p class="receiver-msg">
          {{msg.node.body}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

When I receive a new message. This subscription fires inside this function:

```
listenIncomingMessages() {
this.chatService.messageReceived$
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
  )
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      const newEdge = {
        node: data
      };
      if (data.conversation_id === this.conversationId) {
        this.conversation.messages.edges = <any>[...this.conversation.messages.edges, newEdge];
        // TODO: Scroll to bottom not working
        this.msgContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop =
          this.msgContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop + this.newMesssage.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: wrap it inside setTimeout and check.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Thanks it is scrolling now. But now appending 2 messages instead of 1.

Comment: check whether listenIncomingMessages method is calling twice.

Comment: Work now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngAfterViewChecked` for your help using this [link](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked)

Firstly declare

```
@ViewChild('scrollMe') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;
```

in your .ts file. Then in `ngOnInit()` define these two functions, which will detect chnage in the component and scroll down accordingly.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }



scrollToBottom(): void {
    try {
      this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch (err) { }
  }
```

Comment: Your method works fine. But now I can scroll to top, for loading new messages. Can you suggest something for this.? @BlizZard

Comment: Can you tell me... how do I fix this?

Comment: New requirement is, you want to scroll to top now also? Sorry, I am not able to get you.

Comment: Not a new requirement...But the user should be able to scroll through above messages also

Comment: yes, user can do the same. This function wont interfere on that fucntionality

Comment: Actually, it is blocking me when I want to scroll. Because `afterViewChecked` is invoked. Anyways.. `setTimeout` fixed my problem.
Thanx for your help

Comment: Call `afterViewChecked()` after your message response is retrived by the API/function you are calling from.